# My responsive navbar is not working. I am not able to link on some links

Tags: html, css

I am not able to click on HOME, CATEGORIES and LOGIN link.
The links which are not collapsing with image, they're clickable. Otherwise it won't click.

It was working fine initially when there wasn't any content.
I tried adding javascript and doing it the other way but I was still facing the same issue.

```css
nav {
  background: #14213d;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

label.logo {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 140px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 7px 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

a.active,
a:hover {
  background: #263e72;
  transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 952px) {
  label.logo {
    font-size: 27px;
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .text {
    font-size: 21px
  }
}

@media (max-width: 858px) {
  .checkbtn {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #4d4a46;
  }
  a:hover,
  a.active {
    background: none;
    color: #4d4a46;
    background: #c8d1e4;
  }
  #check:checked~ul {
    left: 0;
  }
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </label>
  <label class="logo"><i id="logo" class="fa fa-book"></i> Book Shoppers</label>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i> CATEGORIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> LOGIN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> WISHLIST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> CUSTOMER SUPPORT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you try to set up a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to replicate the error? I assume that you need to set a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) on the `<nav>` element to make sure it is positioned above the rest of the content.

Comment: Setting a z-index worked. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to write your solution as an answer and mark it as solved by ticking the box on the top left of your answer (this will require a wait time of 1-2 days).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding z-index in the nav of the css file.
This will solve the problem

```
nav {
  background: #14213d;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```